# EF Core Configure entity properties by type with Fluent API

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-fluent-api

I have an entity with with multiple properties of the same type. I want to include all properties of that type in the same table.

You can get individual properties in the same table by calling `OwnsOne(o => o.property)` on the entity. But I want to do this on all properties of that type.

Let's say we have the following (working) example:

```
public class Animal 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public ProvidedLength LengthAtBirth { get; set; }
    public ProvidedLength LengthAtDead { get; set; }
}

public class ProvidedLength 
{
    public DateTime SubmissionDate { get; set; }
    public string Unit { get; set; }
    public string Length { get; set; }
}

public class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyDbContext> options) : base(options) { }

    public DbSet<Animal> Animals { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.ApplyConfiguration(new AnimalConfiguration());
    }
}

class AnimalConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Animal>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Animal> builder)
    {
        // TODO: Apply the OwnsOne configuration all properties of the "ProvidedLength" type
        builder.OwnsOne(a => a.LengthAtBirth);
        builder.OwnsOne(a => a.LengthAtDead);
    }
}
```

Instead of calling each property, I want to do this for the `ProvidedLength` type.

I tried `builder.OwnsOne<ProvidedLength>()` and `builderBuilder.Entity<ProvidedLength>.OwnsOne()`, but in both cases you need to provide the navigationProperty.

Comment: Let me know to reopen the question if the post marked as duplicate is not what are you after.

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted! I did not knew the OwnedAttribute. Thanks!